# What does the \W mean in pattern re.U?

Tags: python, regex, split

I have an text file named gugong.txt with some Chinese and English words in it.I want to extract the Chinese words out . the code is below: 
`note_file = open('gugong.txt','rb')`

```
note_file = open('gugong.txt','rb')
content = note_file.read() 
print type(content)
note_file.close()
sentences = re.split("\W+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+", content, 0, re.UNICODE)
```

I want to ask that: What does the \W mean in  pattern re.U in the last line ? Does it match the Chinese words like \u4E25 ? What is the difference between the re.U and re.L(the default one)?

Answer (score 1):

`\W` means, NOT word. The regular expression will match anything which is not considered a word.

From the docs,

> When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any
>   non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the set
>   [^a-zA-Z0-9_]. With LOCALE, it will match any character not in the set
>   [0-9_], and not defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If
>   UNICODE is set, this will match anything other than [0-9_] plus
>   characters classied as not alphanumeric in the Unicode character
>   properties database.

Comment: Did you mean that it will execute re.split（） if the file has some words like \u4E25 in it and the \u4E25 will be a separator?

Comment: @user2231383 The code which you posted will give you a list of unicode characters found in the file.

Comment: @user2231383 Why so? You want only the chinese characters right?

Comment: Yes you are right~ I got it! At the very start I think the \W will match \u4E25 because \u4E25 is [^a-zA-Z0-9_]. By the way, why  is \W+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+  not universal set ?